# How to run a batch or exe file when clicking to enter a drive or execute itself in windows

Tags: windows-7, boot, shell, batch, autorun

Although a batch file with  executable commands could be run in  different ways, I wonder if there is a way like making "autorun.Inf", which is disabled in windows,to run that "bat" or it's "exe" file when enter any drive in windows 7 or it runs itself depending specified time or actions regardless task scheduler and startup folder ? Could we use Shell commands for this purpose or "system volume information" specified role in windows?

Any idea in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can schedule a task to run on the insertion of a drive. You'd just have to find the correct event and use that as the trigger in Task Scheduler.

Comment: Task scheduler depends on current operating system,so if a new OS is installed, it will no longer operate !

Comment: What is your task exactly? It looks to me as suspicious one...

Comment: Don't worry! in a local network some configuration should be modified for users.

Comment: Well, you'd have to reinstall any other script too, and Tasks can be exported and imported. If you are just trying to re-activate autorun, that's not going to be any easier, and will cause security issues the task-based function would not.

Comment: When clicking on any logical drive,an event handles,so through this there should be a way to make that functionality.

Comment: Shell commands and files like "desktop.ini" are other possibilities.
How windows treats with files inside "system volume information" ?